# What exactly is encoding-independent means

Tags: string, swift

While reading the **Strings and Characters** chapter of the [official Swift document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285) I found the following sentence 
 "*Every string is composed of encoding-independent Unicode characters, and provide support for accessing those characters in various Unicode representations*"

**Question** What exactly do encoding-independent mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my reading on Advanced Swift By Chris and other experiences, the thing that this sentence is trying to convey can be 2 folds.

First, what are various unicode representations:

1. **UTF-8**  : compatible with ASCII
2. **UTF-16**
3. **UTF-32**

The number on the right hand side means how many bits a Character will take when it represented or stored.

For a character, UTF-8 requires 8 bits while UTF-32 requires 32 bits.

However, a chinese character which can be represented by 1 UTF-32 memory might not always fit in 1 block of UTF-16 memory. If the character aquires all 32 bits then in UTF-8 it will have a count of 4.

Then comes the storing part. When you store a character in the String, it doesn't matter how you want to read it later.

For example:
[image]

> Every string is composed of encoding-independent Unicode characters, and provide support for accessing those characters in various Unicode representations

This means, you can compose String by any way you like. And this wont effect the representation when reading on various unicode encoding formats like UTF-8 or 16 or 32.

**This is seen clearly in the above example, When i try to load a Japanese Character which takes up 24 bit to store. The same character is displayed irrespective of my choice of encoding.**

However, count value will differ.  There are other points to consider like Code Unit and Code Point that make up this Strings.

[For Unicode Encoding variants](http://www.interproinc.com/blog/unicode-101-introduction-unicode-standard)

I would highly recommend reading this article which goes way deeper into String api in swift. 
[Detail View of String API in swift](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-06-why-is-swifts-string-api-so-hard.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and explanation. And also the provided source. Very nice staff!